# How to insert a value with single apostrophe in DB2

Tags: java, string, replace, db2

My requirement is to insert a value which contains an apostrophe,(e.g St.Mary's), into DB2 using a java query.

My table has a column name with datatype Char(26) for this purpose and this cannot be changed.

I've handled the apostrophe using the [DB2 Survival guide](http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/db2/db2_survival_guide.htm), this way:

```
String CityName = beanClass.getCity();
        if(CityName.contains("'"))
        {
            CityName.replace("'","''");
        }   
  prepStmt.setString(1, CityName);
```

Query Looks like:

```
INSERT INTO TableName(CityName) VALUES(?);
(Where values are being received from the preparedStatement(Index,String) (prepStmt.setString(int,string))
```

Please help me to insert the value "St.Mary's" with an apostrophe into DB2.

Thanks loads, Varsha.

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about the apostrophe, don't replace it at all. JDBC should handle it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape character for single quote is double single quote. For example, to insert St.Mary's you need to do

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('St.Mary''s')
```

However, it is for plain SQL. It depends how you call it from Java. If the column is a parameter marker in a prepared statement, you do not need that.

Also, if you pass the parameter from other components, probably you need to escape the single quote character.

Comment: The same snippet i'd used above. I get the value as **St.Mary''s** after replacing. Stil am not able to insert it to DB2. Please help!

Comment: I ran this query:
insert into Table values (8,'PRINCE GEORGE''S') 
and am getting this error:
 [Error Code: -117, SQL State: 42802]  THE NUMBER OF ASSIGNED VALUES IS NOT THE SAME AS THE NUMBER OF SPECIFIED OR IMPLIED COLUMNS. SQLCODE=-117, SQLSTATE=42802, DRIVER=4.13.127

Comment: Where are you running the sentence? from CLP? from Java? prepared statement? how many parameter markers?

Answer (score 0):

Replace any single apostrophes with \'

CityName.replace("'","\\'");

\\' results in \' because the first two backslashes results in \

Comment: I did try by replacing \\'. I get the value as **St.Mary\'s** after replacing. Still am not able to insert it to DB2. Not sure why it is so.

Comment: Ran this query:
insert into Table values (8,'PRINCE GEORGE\\'S')
and i got this error:
 [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "S". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.13.127

Comment: The query should be: insert into Table values (8,'PRINCE GEORGE\'S')
Using CityName.replace("'","\\'"); will give you PRINCE GEORGE\'S, not PRINCE GEORGE\\'S

Answer (score 0):

```
 String value1 = "" +jsonObject.get(key)+"";
 if(value1.contains("'")){
    value1 = value1.replace("'", "\''");
}

 value = value +"\'"+value1+"\'";   
// value.replaceAll("\"", "\\" + "\"");
 listofkey+=",";
 value+=",";
```

Comment: Answers with just code are not considered good. Try adding some explanation.

Comment: while inserting values into SQLServer DB, if the Column value has apostrophe it will fails to insert, swe should make that apostrophe as constant so it was replaced where ever it exists by using value.replace() method. Later we can add into values list